# Dynamically updating "Avatar" in tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

On my tumblr page, I want to have an avatar appear next to the blog post for whoever wrote the post. The only way I can think of doing this is having the person add their name in the title of the blog.

Title - Name

Then I would parse it and use the name to grab the right avatar.

This works only for the latest blog. (**NOTE**: This is just a test function!)

```
    function Tom(t)
    {
        if(t)
        {  
            return "JMY";

        }

        return "JIMMY";
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? If not, how do I get the script to run for each blog post, not just the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Post Authors

Tumblr allows multiple authors to post content to a single 'blog'. You can include their information in your theme HTML,  using the following template tags:

`{PostAuthorName}` = Name of the post Author.
`{PostAuthorPortraitURL-48}` = Avatar of the post Author.

Overview of all tags related to Post Authors here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#post-authors

Comment: I didn't realize that, thanks! (I can't upvote you because I don't have 15 rep or else I would!)

I was wondering, is there a way to loop through all the blogs I have posted to dynamically insert information like I was trying to do or is it impossible? -- The {PostAuthorName} is for people posting on my tumblr from another tumblr account, right? So it won't work for sharing the same blog account between two people.

Comment: No problem. This isn't for reblogs, this is for multiple authors on the same blog. The information is always bound (server side) to your post, its just a case of adding the template tag to your theme to display it.